# How do I loop back

Tags: python

I have been trying and reading things online for over 2 hours, with no success. Please help! How do I loop back to line 6 of this code (see below) for an unfixed number of times? I'm aware that it is to do with while looping, but I am really just unsure. The code is designed for somebody to loan a certain quantity of a book/books, but I do not know how to allow them to loan more than one book. Please help, if possible. I understand that this site is not for assignments, but I seriously am struggling here, and if I can be helped, I will know for the future. Here is my code, not very accurate but I am a student learning.

```
task=input("Enter 'b' to borrow a book, press 'x' to exit. \n")
if task.lower()== "b":
    myfile=open("books.txt", "r+") 
    details=myfile.readlines() 
    while True:
        book=input("Enter the 8 digit book code. \n")
        if len(book) !=8 
            print("Your code is not 8 digits long, please try again.\n") 
        else:
            break 
        f = open("books.txt", "r+") #I have a file with all the books, their codes and prices
        for line in f.readlines():
            quantity=input("How many copies of the book do you wish to purchase?\n")
            t = line.split(" ")
            price = float(t[3])
            code = t[1]
            NameOfBook = t[2]
            total=(price)* int(quantity)
        # Ask them if they'd like to purchase more books, if so I would like to then direct them back to  "book=input("Enter the 8 digit book code. \n")"

            print ("Your receipt is:",digits,"," ,name, name2) #How can I repeat this for however many books they'd like to purchase?
            print ("Your total is £",total) #Then add the total cost of everything together and print it
```

The hashes show what I would like to happen. thanks in advance and im sorry for being annoying

Comment: Indent everything from line 11 (except the last 2 lines) another level so it is within the `while` block. Python is layout sensitive and indentation indicated blocks.

Comment: Okay will do.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can place the for loop code under the else statement, and then add another statement at the end to ask if the user wants to complete another transaction. If so, continue, else, break. Here is what you can do:

```
task=input("Enter 'b' to borrow a book, press 'x' to exit. \n")
if task.lower()== "b":
     myfile=open("books.txt", "r+") 
     details=myfile.readlines() 
     while True:
          book=input("Enter the 8 digit book code. \n")
          if len(book) !=8 
                print("Your code is not 8 digits long, please
               try again.\n") 
          else:

               f = open("books.txt", "r+") 
               for line in f.readlines():
                     quantity=input("How many copies of the book do   
                    you wish to purchase?\n")
                     t = line.split(" ")
                     price = float(t[3])
                     code = t[1]
                     NameOfBook = t[2]
                     total=(price)* int(quantity)
                     print ("Your receipt is:",digits,"," ,name,  
                      name2) 
                     print ("Your total is £",total)
               answer = input("Do you want to enter another book?")
               if answer == "yes":
                    continue
               else:
                    break
```